# how to retrieve images based on a category in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a project and got stuck in the drop down list, I need to get the images based on the category selected from the drop down list, for this I have two tables category and Images 
 model

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ImgTitle { get; set; }
    public string ImgUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Category()
    {
        this.Images = new HashSet<Image>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

categoryId is the foreign key to the Images class. by category wise I have added images.

controller

```
    public ActionResult Gallery()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "CatName");
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult GetImageRecord(int Id)
    {
        var img = db.Images.Where(e => e.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_TestPartial", img);
    }
```

view

```
  @model ckeditor.Models.Image


  @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.CategoryId,"category")
   @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddl" })
  <div id="partialDiv">
  @Html.Partial("_TestPartial")
  </div>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ddl").on("change", function () {

        url: '/Gallery/GetImageRecord/' + $("#ddl option:selected").val(),

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Gallery/GetImageRecord/' + $("#ddl option:selected").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            data: "",
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#partialDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

partial page

```
 @model List<ckeditor.Models.Image>


 <div class="row">
  @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Count(); j++)
   {
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Pictures/" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[j].ImgUrl))" style="width:auto;height:300px;" />
}
```

I have used jquery and ajax to retrieve the the images from table and also the selected index to change as selected from drop down list. here I didn't get any error but not getting the images as in the category I am selected . Can anyone please help me to get to solve the problem, to show images ??

Comment: `db.Images.Where(e => e.CategoryId == Id).ToList();`

Comment: Getting error in @for (var j = 0; j < Model.Count(); j++) that Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source, why is this occurred? Have value in table for each category

Comment: Because you have `@Html.Partial("_TestPartial")` in your main view but you have not passes a model to that partial so its `null`. Just delete that (or use `@Html.Partial("_TestPartial",new List<Image>())` to pass an empty collection